# permutation of an integer without loops in C

Tags: c, recursion, permutation

I have to write a recursive function called permute that gets a int n and other parameters if needed, without using any loops. (no limitation on function's signature). I'm only allowed to call a printArray (or another assistance function) function from inside the permute function.

basically i thought of start printing the array (first output is 1 2 3) and for every digit i printed, note it (with a flag maybe, other ways would be appreciated). in the next row i will not print 2 for example because i raised a flag and when my flag will be raised i'll know that i have to make the swap. 
my problems are how to use the flag properly, when to raise, how to take it down back. i'm not finding the flag way very useful here although i'm pretty sure its the best way.
any suggestions to fix my code would be appreciated. right now my output for input 3 is:

1 2 3

2 1 3

2 1 3

2 3 1

```
void permute (int arr[], int flagArr[], int size, int index){
    int temp;
    if (index == size - 1){
        printf ("\n");
        flagArr[index] = 0;
        return;
    }
    else if (flagArr[index] == 1){
        temp = arr[index];
        arr[index] = arr[index + 1];
        arr[index + 1] = temp;
        flagArr[index] = 0;
        print_array(arr, flagArr, 0, size);
        permute (arr, flagArr, size, index+1);
    }
    else{
        print_array (arr,flagArr, 0, size);
        flagArr[index] = 1;
        permute (arr,flagArr, size, index);
        return;
    }
}
    void print_array (int arr[], int flagArr[], int index, int size){
        if (index == size){
            printf ("\n");
            return;
        }
        else {
            printf ("%d ",arr[index]);
            print_array (arr, flagArr, index + 1, size);
        }

    }
```

for example: input 3 and the output should be:

All permutations of numbers (1 2 3):
1 2 3

1 3 2

2 1 3

2 3 1

3 1 2

3 2 1

**UPDATE**: no static variable and pointers allowed.

Comment: I'd ask the teacher "why must we learn how to write bad code". Recursion is almost never the correct solution for anything in C. The only uses are a few search/sort algorithms where you must optimize static memory use by not permanently storing a "previous" pointer - while at the same time guaranteeing tail-call optimization. There barely exists any such use case in the real world.